# Asp.net web site and web service hosting

Tags: asp.net, sql, web-services, web-hosting

I have a web site and a web service and I would like to host them somewhere.
I need to use it mostly for testing and so that a some friends who are developing some applications to use the service have access to it. Also the service is using a MS SQL 2008 database.

Could you suggest any good free or cheap web hosting service for this. I would need about 1-2 months of hosting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

winhost.com

OR

discountasp.net

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

http://www.aspspider.com/

They support ASP.NET and SQL server 2008. Also they do not post ads on your pages.

"AspSpider offers free web hosting with ASP.NET 4.0 and SQL Server 2005/2008 support. This     is an absolutely free offer from a group of .NET programmers for the peer technical community."

Comment: "We closed our free hosting program on 31 May 2008. Effective 1 July 2008, we are launching a new program.

Members are allowed to create a web site and host here for 90 days from the date of creating the website. After 90 days, your website will expire and all files will be deleted.

After the 90 day period, you are allowed to re create a website, but not under the same domain name. For example, if your current url is http://aspspider.net/butterfly, after 90 day period, you will have to change it to something like http://aspspider.org/butterfly 

- Tony"

Answer (score 0):

[justhost.com](http://www.justhost.com)

OR

[godaddy.com](http://www.godaddy.com)

Answer (score 0):

You could check out [Station5.net](http://www.station5.net), I like them.

Answer (score 0):

[ReliableSite](http://www.reliablesite.net/v3/shared-special.asp) has a shared special for $3/mo including a free MS SQL 2008 database, probably as cheap as it gets.